# How to control spacing between tick values and change format

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could anyone suggest how to change the code I have so that I have:
- more spaced out tick values, in units of 0.5
- format every tick label as 1 decimal place

This is where I am at the moment:

[image: current output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-] (-1,0) -- (2.5,0);
\draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (2.5,0);
\foreach \x in  {0,1,2}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,1pt) -- (0pt,-1pt);
\foreach \x in {0,0.5,1,1.5}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
%\node at (2.5,-1) {\text{Number of smart devices purchased}};
\draw[fill=black] (0,0.5) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (0,1.0) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (0,1.5) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (1,0.5) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (1,1.0) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (2,0.5) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (2,1.0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of digits can be fixed e.g. by saying `\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\x}`. To stretch the horizontal direction (without deforming the circles) you could use `x={(1.5,0)}`, say.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1.5,0)}]
\draw[latex-latex] (-1,0) -- (2.5,0);
\foreach \x in  {0,1,2}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,1pt) -- (0pt,-1pt);
\foreach \x in {0,0.5,1,1.5}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below] 
{$\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\x}$};
\draw[fill=black] (0,0.5) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (0,1.0) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (0,1.5) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (1,0.5) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (1,1.0) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (2,0.5) circle (2pt);
\draw[fill=black] (2,1.0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You were loading `pgfplots` (as well as many packages which are not really related to the example), but not using it. With `pgfplots` you could also do the plot e.g. by an `only marks,mark=*` plot, and then it will be less pain to add the ticks.

Comment: Thanks for this. What I meant by "more spaced out" is simply: how to stretch the axis, so that the numbers don't touch each other.

Comment: @WillKim I made an update.